# Python requests: get attributes from returned JSON string

Tags: python, json, http, python-requests

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://httpbin.org/get');
r.text
```

returns:

```
u'{\n  "url": "http://httpbin.org/get",\n  "headers": {\n    "Host": "httpbin.org",\n    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, compress",\n    "Connection": "close",\n    "Accept": "*/*",\n    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.7.5 Windows/7",\n    "X-Request-Id": "db302999-d07f-4dd6-8c1e-14db45d39fb0"\n  },\n  "origin": "61.228.172.190",\n  "args": {}\n}'
```

How can get the `origin` and `headers/Host` values?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What's being returned is a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) string; you need to parse it before you can conveniently use it. Requests can do this for you if you call `r.json()` instead of `r.text`.

```
resp = r.json()
print resp['origin']
print resp['headers']['Host']
```

Comment: `r.text` may use a wrong character encoding, just use `r.json()` always

Comment: why I get string from json() ?

Comment: could be various reasons.