# python json file read and print category

Tags: python-2.7

I have to read and print the category and value inside the array. The code is as below.

If you could help me with.
PS this is a from my JSON file.

```
{
  "dimension": [
    {
      "label": "COUNTRY",
      "display": "Country",
      "isMeasure": false,
      "code": [
        {
          "attr": [
            {
              "category": "WORLD_BANK_INCOME_GROUP",
              "value": "Lower-middle-income"
            },   
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
}
```

Here is my code

```html
with open('C:\Users\dell1023\Desktop\OFFICE PROJECT\PYTHON\COUNTRY.json', 'r') as json_data:
    data1 = json_data.read()
    data1
    data = js.loads(data1)
    a = data['dimension'][0]['code'][0]['attr'][0]['category']
    print a
```

But there are more than 100 of lists in attribute.
inside the code there is more than one attr. I want to print all the category of attr.

Comment: Where's your code?

Comment: you missed some ']' in your json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python requests: get attributes from returned JSON string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231869/python-requests-get-attributes-from-returned-json-string)

Comment: Here is the complete json code:
{
  "dimension": [
    {
      "label": "COUNTRY",
      "display": "Country",
      "isMeasure": false,
      "code": [
        {
          "attr": [
            {
              "category": "WORLD_BANK_INCOME_GROUP",
              "value": "Lower-middle-income"
            },   
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
}

Comment: @androidnoobdev 
tried this one but there is an error.
    print data['attribute']['label']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

MY CODE IS THIS
with open('C:\Users\dell1023\Desktop\OFFICE PROJECT\PYTHON\COUNTRY.json', 'r') as json_data:
##    data = js.load (json_data)
    data1 = json_data.read()
    data1
    data = js.loads(data1)
    print data['attribute']['code']['attr']['category']

Comment: @josham please avoid including a large portion of code as a comment. Alternatively use the main question area.

Comment: @josham Welcome to SO. along with Python you'll be able to appreciate Patience as well. Wait till people contribute. I know nothing about Python.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over `'attr'` array:

```
data = js.loads(data1)
for a in data['dimension'][0]['code'][0]['attr']:
    print a['category']
```